# How to rename programs installed from the app store

Tags: software-center

Previously I had blender 2.79b installed (from the app store) on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine. I just installed blender 2.8 (also from the app store). They both launch, but the only way I can tell them apart is a slight difference in the icons. I would like to keep both of them installed, so if there is any way to rename them from "Blender" to "Blender 2.79" and "Blender 2.8" that would be great (or just generally how to rename a program installed from the app store).

Comment: maybe create a `.dektop` file with the name you want pointing to the corresponding executable

Comment: "They both launch, but the only way I can tell them apart is a slight difference in the icons." most logical answer: change the icon.

Comment: @Rinzwind Also, I cannot launch one of them from the terminal, which is problematic since the application requires a launch from the terminal to function properly.

Comment: Ok, I managed to find the Blender .desktop files, which I edited and this fixed the problem. Thank you everyone for the help.